# Convert text file to list then run functions on each list item in python?

Tags: python, list

Please bear with my this is my second week "coding". This is probably easy for you guys but it's really hard for me.
I'm stuck on an assignment for class. I need to save 5 passwords to a txt file, create a module to test if its a valid/strong password(8 characters, 1 upper, 1 lower, 1 special)

I have imported my function: `password_check()` but I cant figure out how to make it check each item in the list. I can do something like this:

```
pwd_file = open("passwords.txt", "r")
passwords = pwd_file.read()
print(passwords)
password_list = passwords.split(",")

from passval import password_check
password_check(password_list[0])
password_check(password_list[1])
password_check(password_list[2])
password_check(password_list[3])
password_check(password_list[4])
```

But it feels like cheating because I know how many items are in the list. Is there a better way to run a function on each list item?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [for loop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements). It iterates over the items of any sequence such as your `password_list`

```
for password in password_list:
    password_check(password)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop to validate/check it in dynamically

```
pwd_file = open("passwords.txt", "r")
passwords = pwd_file.read()
print(passwords)
password_list = passwords.split(",")

for password in password_list:
    password_check(password)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with a good practice - using:

```
with open(file) as variable:
```

In your example variable would be pwd_file. It automaticly closes the file when you go back to your normal indentation. Apart from that, after using .split() method you have list of passwords, so you can iterate over them with for loop:

```
for password in list_name:
    password_check(password)
```